Configure MQ to authenticate using LDAP (MS Active Directory)
I am configuring an MQ Queue Manager (v9.3, on z/Linux) to authenticate using LDAP (Microsoft AD) for the first time and so far, I had no luck.
The AD server I need to connect to does not accept unsecure connections, so I need to connect using TLS, and I could not pass through the very first step: bind to the AD
What I tried:
At runmqsc:
DEFINE AUTHINFO(LDAP.MSAD) +
AUTHTYPE(IDPWLDAP) +
ADOPTCTX(YES) +
DESCR('LDAP Connector to MSAD' ) +
CONNAME('msad.acme.com(636)') +
CHCKCLNT(OPTIONAL) +
CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +                   
CLASSGRP('group') +
CLASSUSR('user') +                      
FAILDLAY(1) +
FINDGRP('member') +
BASEDNG('DC=msad,DC=acme,DC=com') +
BASEDNU('DC=msad,DC=acme,DC=com') +
LDAPUSER('CN=mybind,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=msad,DC=acme,DC=com') +
LDAPPWD('my_supersecret_passw0rd') +
SHORTUSR('sAMAccountName') +              
GRPFIELD('cn') +
USRFIELD('sAMAccountName') +             
AUTHORMD(SEARCHUSR) +
NESTGRP(NO) +
SECCOMM(YES) +
REPLACE

ALT QMGR CONNAUTH(LDAP.MSAD)

Setup the key.kdb
# Created key.kdb
  runmqakm -keydb -create -db key.kdb -pw passw0rd -type cms -stash
  
# Converted my CA Root cert, from PEM to DER format
  openssl x509 -in ./ca_root.pem -outform der -out ./ca_root.der
  
# Added CA Root to key.kdb
  runmqakm -cert -add -db key.kdb -stashed -label "ACME Internal Root CA" -file ./ca_root.der -format ascii
  
# Confirmed that the cert was imported
  runmqakm -cert -list -db key.kdb -stashed

And finally...
echo "REFRESH SECURITY" | runmqsc

I am sure that the bind id/password, as well as the root certificate, are good, as they are being used on WAS in the same server, and I can use them to run ldapsearch however, the message that I get printed on QM AMQERR01.LOG clearly shows that the bind to AD was unsuccessful
----- amqzfula.c : 3451 -------------------------------------------------------
09/04/2024 01:46:28 PM - Process(4100598.22) User(mqm) Program(amqzlaa0)
                    Host(myserver) Installation(Installation1)
                    VRMF(9.3.0.17) QMgr(MYQM)
                    Time(2024-09-04T20:46:28.479Z)
                    ArithInsert1(81)
                    CommentInsert1(ldap_simple_bind)
                    CommentInsert2(Can't contact LDAP server)
                    CommentInsert3(CN=mybind,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=msad,DC=acme,DC=com )

AMQ5530E: Error from LDAP authentication and authorization service

EXPLANATION:
The LDAP authentication and authorization service has failed. The
'ldap_simple_bind' call returned error 81 : 'Can't contact LDAP server'.  The
context string is
'CN=mybind,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=msad,DC=acme,DC=com
'. Additional code is 0.
ACTION:
Correct the LDAP configuration. Look at the LDAP server logs for additional
error information.
----- amqzfula.c : 3451 -------------------------------------------------------

Unfortunately, I don't have access to the AD server log.
Clearly, I am missing some basic step at the very beginning, but I can't identify it! Can someone help, please?

Are you sure your CONNAME can be resolved on the queue manager machine? Can you TCP ping it from that machine?

Try echo "REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(SSL)"  | runmqsc instead.

And is that kdb file the one configured for the qmgr?

And depending on the TLS config for your server and the qmgr, you might also want to try SECCOMM(ANON).

@MoragHughson Yes, CONNAME is pingable, and I can use it successfully with ldapsearch;
@JoshMc I tried REFRESH SECURITY with (*), TYPE(SSL) and TYPE(AUTHSERV), and the error still persist;
@MarkTaylor yes, key.kdb is the one configured at qmgr's SSLKEYR (w/o extension, as it should be)
Additionally, I have recycled the QM, and the error persists.

Did you try SECCOMM(ANON),?

yes @JoshMc, I forgot to mention it in my reply, but I tried it with no luck.

I suggest you open a case with IBM.  They will probably have you capture the issue on a trace and send it on for review.

How do you expect this to work with SECCOM(YES) when that means the QM would authenticate with its cert and you are only adding a signer cert?
